# Magit: edit Git command before running it

Tags: magit

I would like to manually edit the Git command run by a Magit popup. Is there a way to do this?

For example, in `magit-log-popup`, I want to add `--date default` to the `git log` command that Magit is going to run. The `--date` option is not one of the options supported by the log popup.

**UPDATE**: Feature request: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2700.

Comment: Log a feature request for manual editing of the final command as a generic option? It would be nice to have it as an option everywhere. I would suggest that `:` could be bound in pop-ups to set an option that gets picked up by the eventual "execute the command" code (which then provides the interactive prompt).

Comment: @phils: Good idea; done: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2700 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I likely won't be adding this feature to the current implementation in `magit-popup.el` but I will consider adding it to the planned successor `transient`. See the open [issue #2700](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2700) on Github for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add your own option to the popup

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-log-popup
  ?D "Date" "--date=" #'read-from-minibuffer)
```

Now when the popup is open and you press  <kbd>=D</kbd>  you can enter the date option that you would like.

You can learn more on the [magit wiki](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Additional-proposed-infix-arguments-and-suffix-commands)

Comment: Thanks, but there is a one-off way to do this, by directly editing the Git command that Magit is going to use? E.g. now I would also like to add `--pickaxe-regex`, but I don't want to add another `magit-define-popup-option` for every new option.

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer but what if you make an option that has an empty 4th argument so instead of "--date=" you had "". Then when you prompted you enter anything you want

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think quoting cretes a problem here: it seems that Magit quotes the argument to the option, so e.g. `--date default` becomes `"--date default"`.

Comment: @ntc2 So having `(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-log-popup ?G "General" "" #'read-from-minibuffer)` and then typing "--date=default" in the prompt would not work?

Comment: Using the equal sign to avoid whitespace seems to work, but it's buggy: e.g. Magit prepopulates the `=G` option with `--graph`, and does not remember the actual value that I used between invocations. And this hack doesn't help me pass two options, where whitespace seems essential.

Comment: Well darn... One thing you can possbily do is edit the variable `magit-log-arguments` and then change it back afterwards but I feel like just defining a new option might be easier. I'm at a loss for another solution

Comment: Adding this feature to Magit, as suggested by phils, seems like a good way to go.